# Simple calculator - "Resource leak: op is never closed" does it harm to not close Scanner?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

my questions are the following:
 - why does eclipse want me  to close the Scanners? Does it any harm to not close them? Do I profit if I close them?
 - Is there beginner mistake in my code? What would an java expert solve different?

I have left out subtraction(), multiplication(), division() and modulo() from my code because they work almost the same like addition().

```
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

 class Calculator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static boolean invalid = true;

    static void addition() throws InputMismatchException {
        do {
            try {
                Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
                Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
                double a1 = a.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter a number to add it to " + a1 + ": ");
                double a2 = b.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(a1 + " + " + a2 + " = " + (a1 + a2));
                invalid = false;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Oops! Please enter only numbers!");
                invalid = true;
            }
        } while (invalid == true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int o;
        boolean turnOff = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("Choose from one of the operation options.\n"
                    + "Type 1 for addition\n" + "     2 for substraction\n"
                    + "     3 for multiplication\n" + "     4 for division\n"
                    + "     5 for modulo\n");

            Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
            o = op.nextInt();

            switch (o) {
            case 1:
                addition();
                break;
            case 2:
                subtraction();
                break;
            case 3:
                multiplication();
                break;
            case 4:
                division();
            case 5:
                modulo();
            }
            do {
                System.out.print("Do you want to do more calculations? (n = no, y = yes) ");
                Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
                char input = c.next().charAt(0);
                if (input == 'y') {
                    turnOff = false;
                    invalid = false;
                } else if (input == 'n') {
                    turnOff = true;
                    invalid = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("y or n is the only valid input. Try again.");
                    invalid = true;
                }
            } while (invalid == true);
        } while (turnOff == false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally not closing an `AutoCloseable` (e.g. a `FileInputStream`) is a mistake that would result in a resource leak, hence the warning.

But you're right to ask the question here.  Say if you were to follow Eclipse's suggestion and close `Scanner a`, that would actually close the `System.in` that it's wrapping.

Stylewise I would be tempted to use a single `Scanner` instance all the way through, probably as an instance variable in the Calculator class.  Firstly this would side step the Eclipse warning, but will also be (slightly) more efficient.